# About click or hover functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have a code, when you click the icon, a div appears.
We want to make it appear when hover on icon, not click.
How can we do it?

This code is in my Wordpress theme's footer section.
It needs a change to work like i want. Code is this:

```js
        <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var searchi = 0;
    $("#social-medias").click(function(){
     $("#medias-icons").slideToggle("fast");
                    if ( searchi == 0 ){
                        $(this).addClass("searchAct1");
                        searchi = 1; 
                    }else{
                        $(this).removeClass("searchAct1");
                        searchi = 0;
                    }
    });
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: Wild guess, replace `click` with `mouseenter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `.click(function() { //code here; });` use `.mouseover(function() { //code here; });`

then to get it to undo, use `.mouseout(function() { //reverse code here; });`

Comment: it works. thank you. but it need to hover again to disappear. how can i make it disappear when i get mouse cursor away from the icon?

Comment: @sezeri. i'll take a shot at it, give me a couple minutes

Comment: @sezeri. http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/195/ i think this is what you're looking for. i changed `slideToggle()` to `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`

Comment: thank you so much! but when i put the cursor on #medias-icons div, it slides up :/ how can i make it stop when i put cursor on #medias-icons div?

Comment: @sezeri. you pretty much code something along the lines of "if mouseover  #socialmedias or #media-icons, then show #media-icons"

Answer (score 0):

I see these elements are nested, so you can achieve this using only styles

```
.a{
color:blue;
}
.a .b{
    color:red;
}
.a:hover .b{
    color:green;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
    a
    <div class="b">
        b
    </div>
</div>
```

Following this example, you can override nested classes behaviour(e.g. display:none/block) when cursor is over it's parent (hover)